# Filtering data by time only in datetime column for sql

Tags: python, sql, filter

Working with sqlite in Python.

I have data timestamped

```
2022-05-22 00:57:28
2022-05-22 14:40:18
2022-05-22 02:58:32
2022-05-22 03:59:30
2022-05-22 15:07:17
```

I would like to get all rows that fall in between a TIME range.

This produces no results

```
SELECT *
FROM speedtests 
WHERE date_run BETWEEN time("00:00:00") AND time("06:00:00")
```

I tried the solution from a similar question, however it returns every single result in the database.

```
select * from table
where cast(date_run as time) >= '00:00:00'
   OR cast(date_run as time) <= '06:00:00'
```

I have also tried GROUP BY statements but could not get it to work.

If getting individual rows is not possible, the max, min, avg, count values are enough for the filtered dataset - aggregate statement which I also tried with no luck.

Comment: which rdms are you using?

Comment: Your sample data has no datetime between 00:00:00 and 06:00:00. On the other hand, in your query where you cast as time, you are looking for times later than 06:00:00 *or* before 00:00:00, which fit all your (sample and every possible) data

Comment: I should have chosen better sample data, but i have edited the data/queres to reflect the question better.

Comment: I am using sqlite as per first line in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT *
FROM Table_Name
WHERE time(Column_Name) BETWEEN ('14:30:00') AND ('14:55:00')

Above Query is to filter the data based on time, Replace Table_Name with your table name and Column_Name with your column name for what you want to filter the data.

[image]

Comment: that works! Was placing the time() type in the wrong place. Thank you!